# jqGrid: How to use single search with joined queries?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

Im using the Position table in my jQgrid as my main source of data.

```
Department

id | department
1  | field
2  | IT
3  | Marketing

Position

id | position    | department
5  | interviewee | 1
9  | advertiser  | 3
8  | developer   | 2
```

When I search for ID & Position, I get the results but when I search for the department, it will not work unless I use the ids (1, 2, 3)

I've tried implementing if statements where searching ID, position and department have different queries.

My problem is if I use more columns, then I would have to create queries to each database table I use.

Is there an alternative to this?

Edit:

Here's my current query.

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.position AS position, d.department AS department FROM position p LEFT JOIN department d ON p.department = d.id " . $where ." ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit
```

The `$where` variable is obtained through...

```
function getWhereClause($col, $oper, $val){
    global $ops;
    if($oper == 'bw' || $oper == 'bn') $val .= '%';
    if($oper == 'ew' || $oper == 'en' ) $val = '%'.$val;
    if($oper == 'cn' || $oper == 'nc' || $oper == 'in' || $oper == 'ni') $val = '%'.$val.'%';
    return " WHERE p.$col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";
}
```

... notice that I had to add p. to $col for the search function to work.

I have tried this

```
if($col == 'Department'){
    return " WHERE d.$col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";
    }
    else{
    return " WHERE p.$col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";
    }
```

but for some reason `if($col == 'Department')` isnt being recognized and skips to the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a table that only has the Position ID, Position and Department Name you can use:

```
SELECT position.id, position.position, department.department
FROM Position 
INNER JOIN department on position.department = department.id
```

This way you can search it on Position ID, Position and Department Name instead of ID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However Im still getting the same result as my old query. I'll update my post